# Cannot interact with netcat server over distance

Tags: server, xmlhttprequest, netcat

My friend and I have ran netcat servers with the following commands

```
nc -nlvp 4444

nc -lvp 4444
```

We have also set it up so that any connections on port 4444 can go through the firewall. We have tested and our servers can interact with out phones but only when they are at the same house. We have tried changing things up with using mobile data but the problem persisted.
We have been sending connections via Xhr with the following commands,

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://*my ip was here*", true);
xhr.send();
```

We have tried changing lots of random settings and turning off firewalls.